Why is WebStorm constantly in a "paused indexing" state?
Since about a week, I'm constantly getting this status in WebStorm, which I have to resume manually. It's very distracting and when I resume it finished quickly, so there doesn't seem to be a good reason to pause it. I couldn't find anything in the settings or on Google, which is why I'm posting here.
I also never got this "paused indexing" before. And there is also no way to see the full text :/
If this questions should go to another StackExchange site, please let me know.


It seems Google Geminis answer helped :)

